# Reading cassandra data into pyspark DataFrame

Tags: cassandra, pyspark

I launch pyspark as follows:

```
[idf@node1 python]$ pyspark --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.0.0.60
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
16/05/18 10:52:08 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/05/18 10:52:10 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.11 (default, Dec  6 2015 18:08:32)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
```

When I try to do something simple, I get a stack frame of errors that are of no help:

```
In [1]: import pyspark_cassandra

In [2]: user = sc.cassandraTable("tickdata", "timeseries").toDF()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-59f7356f4bac> in <module>()
----> 1 user = sc.cassandraTable("tickdata", "timeseries").toDF()

/home/idf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark_cassandra-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/pyspark_cassandra/context.pyc in cassandraTable(self, *args, **kwargs)
     28     def cassandraTable(self, *args, **kwargs):
     29         """Returns a CassandraTableScanRDD for the given keyspace and table"""
---> 30         return CassandraTableScanRDD(self, *args, **kwargs)

/home/idf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark_cassandra-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/pyspark_cassandra/rdd.pyc in __init__(self, ctx, keyspace, table, row_format, read_conf, **read_conf_kwargs)
    233         read_conf = as_java_object(ctx._gateway, self.read_conf.settings())
    234 
--> 235         self.crdd = self._helper \
    236             .cassandraTable(
    237                 ctx._jsc,

/home/idf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark_cassandra-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/pyspark_cassandra/rdd.pyc in _helper(self)
    130     @property
    131     def _helper(self):
--> 132         return helper(self.ctx)
    133 
    134 

/home/idf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark_cassandra-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/pyspark_cassandra/util.pyc in helper(ctx)
     91 
     92     if not _helper:
---> 93         _helper = load_class(ctx, "pyspark_cassandra.PythonHelper").newInstance()
     94 
     95     return _helper

/home/idf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark_cassandra-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/pyspark_cassandra/util.pyc in load_class(ctx, name)
     83 def load_class(ctx, name):
     84     return ctx._jvm.java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() \
---> 85             .loadClass(name)
     86 
     87 _helper = None

/opt/spark-latest/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    814 
    815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/spark-latest/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/spark-latest/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o20.loadClass.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pyspark_cassandra.PythonHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


In [3]:
```

**Edit 1**

Doing this gets me much further

```
[idf@node1 python]$ pyspark --packages TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra:0.3.5 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.0.0.60
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/idf/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/idf/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
TargetHolding#pyspark-cassandra added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found TargetHolding#pyspark-cassandra;0.3.5 in spark-packages
    found com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10;1.6.0-M1 in list
    found com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.10;1.6.0-M1 in list
    found org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;3.0.2 in list
    found com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0 in list
    found io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.netty#netty-transport;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.netty#netty-codec;4.0.33.Final in central
    found io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.2 in list
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 in list
    found org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.3.2 in list
    found com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 in list
    found org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 in list
    found joda-time#joda-time;2.3 in list
    found com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 in list
    found org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5 in list
:: resolution report :: resolve 902ms :: artifacts dl 18ms
    :: modules in use:
    TargetHolding#pyspark-cassandra;0.3.5 from spark-packages in [default]
    com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0 from list in [default]
    com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10;1.6.0-M1 from list in [default]
    com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.10;1.6.0-M1 from list in [default]
    com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 from list in [default]
    com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 from list in [default]
    io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.2 from list in [default]
    io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-codec;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-transport;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    joda-time#joda-time;2.3 from list in [default]
    org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;3.0.2 from list in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.3.2 from list in [default]
    org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 from list in [default]
    org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5 from list in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 from list in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   18  |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   18  |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 18 already retrieved (0kB/22ms)
16/05/18 12:06:12 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.11 (default, Dec  6 2015 18:08:32)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.

In [1]: import pyspark_cassandra

In [2]: rdd = sc.cassandraTable("tickdata", "timeseries")
16/05/18 12:08:36 WARN ClosureCleaner: Expected a closure; got pyspark_cassandra.ToRow$
16/05/18 12:08:36 WARN ClosureCleaner: Expected a closure; got pyspark_util.BatchPickler

In [3]:
```

Comment: How do you include pyspark-cassandra?

Comment: Not sure I understand? At top I say  import pyspark_cassandra

Comment: Do I have to add something to the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyspark-cassandra` requires both Python and Scala code to work. Since from your question it is not clear how you include the package my guess is you only added Python code to the `PYTHONPATH`.

If you use Spark with Scala 2.10 (default build for Spark <= 1.6) you can use `pyspark-cassandra` with `--packages`:

```
pyspark --packages TargetHolding:pyspark-cassandra:0.3.5 \
        --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.0.0.60
```

otherwise you'll have to build it by yourself using `--jars`, `--driver-class-path` and `--py-files` arguments (all three are required).

Comment: Thanks that gets me much futher. See Edit 1. Does that output look ok?

Comment: I get those weird In [2]: rdd = sc.cassandraTable("tickdata", "timeseries")
16/05/18 12:08:36 WARN ClosureCleaner: Expected a closure; got pyspark_cassandra.ToRow$
16/05/18 12:08:36 WARN ClosureCleaner: Expected a closure; got pyspark_util.BatchPickler

Comment: Yes, it looks fine. I am not sure. Regarding the warnings I don't think these are anything you should worry about.